# Cannot Drag Webparts in IE=Edge compatible mode

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Can we make edit to master page or layout pages saying , when the page is in edit mode, change compatibility to IE = 10??

I tried,

it did not work..

please let me know how to do this?????

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about classic pages like publishing. 
Dragging web parts in SharePoint online has been discontinued and MS has stated that it will not come back. On modern pages it works fine with most browsers

Comment: if we make change to IE = edge, the dragging webparts is not working on Internet explorer, if we revert back to IE=10, we can drage webparts. i need IE=edge for some pages where we use brightcove videos. so, i am assuming is ther any solution for switching IE modes when page turn to edit mode, then we can drag webparts.

Comment: We have moved away from IE and all customers receive instructions about how to move the web parts using the Zone and Zone index as this works with all browser